# reactjs: Displaying an array data inside <tr> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am getting the response from an api in this way
`data:Array(3)
0:"new"
1:"ruby"
2:"ruby"`

I want to display this data under a tr element inside a jsx expression. I made a loop to traverse through the array like this

```js
let course = [];
  let userid = this.props.match.params.userid;
  axios.get("someapi") //the api to hit request
   .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
     console.log(response.data[i]);
     course.push(response.data[i]);
    }
    console.log("course", course);
    this.setState({ course: course });
    console.log("state course", this.state.course);
   });
```

I am getting all the values in both `console.log`, with "course" and "state course" but can't map it inside tbody to display it in tr tag. I want to render it inside this

```html
<tbody>

  <tr>new,ruby and ruby should be displayed here as a list</tr>

</tbody>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: post all your code, especially what you are rendering

Comment: you're not mapping `this.state.course`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your table

```
<tbody>
{this.state.course.map(ele => 
   <tr>{ele}</tr>
)}
</tbody>
```

this should work.

You can also refer to React doc's section: [List and Key.](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: says cannot read property map of undefined.

Comment: Make sure it’s initialize as an array in your constructor

Comment: Yes, it worked.Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all three courses inside the same `<tr>` tag as a list you could try:

```
let course = [];
let userid = this.props.match.params.userid;
axios.get("someapi") //the api to hit request
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        course = response.data.join(", ");
        console.log("course", course);
        this.setState({ course: course });
        console.log("state course", this.state.course);
    });
```

Then use the `course` variable in your jsx inside the `<tr>` tag.

If you want to print one `tr` for each course set `courses` equal to `response.data` and map through it in your jsx